# How to convert decision rules to a scikit-learn decision tree model?

Tags: scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am trying to use some decision rules to predict whether a satellite image is cloudy or not based on multiple images. As I am new to this, I reshaped the 2D image to 1D for the application of decision tree algorithm while the numper of pixel in each image is around 120M. The huge data size is making the processing slow, is there any better way to do that or take care of that huge data?

Another problem is I am trying to use some already established decision rules, which I can implement by if else statement even in 2D. I know there are ways to convert and display a decision tree visually. But is there any way to convert a visual decision tree to a decision tree model? I mean when you know the decision rules, how can I use that information to convert it to a scikit learn model??

By visual decision tree I meant something like following image.

[image]

Comment: https://medium.com/@rnbrown/creating-and-visualizing-decision-trees-with-python-f8e8fa394176

Comment: @ScottBoston the example you have shown is converting a data to a model and visualize it. I need the opposite, I know the decision rles, just need to add those to a model so that I can reuse it anytime. Thanks